# C code runs on the online compiler perfectly but on VS CODE, CODEBLOCKS, AND VISUAL STUDIO IT goes in an infinite loop

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct element
{
    int value;
    struct element *leftelement;
    struct element *rightelement;
} *root;


void search(int value)
{
    struct element *current = root;
    printf("searching for %d\n", value);
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d -> ", current->value);
        
        if (current->value == value)
        {
            printf("Value found\n");
            return;
        }
        
        if (current->value > value)
            current = current->leftelement;
        else
            current = current->rightelement;
        
    }
    printf("Value not found\n");
}



void insert(int value)
{
    struct element *tempelement = (struct element *)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
    tempelement->value = value;
    struct element *currPos = root;
    struct element *parent = NULL;
    printf("Inserting the value %d\n", value);
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = tempelement;
        return;
    }
    
    while (1)
    {
        printf("%d -> ", currPos->value);
        parent = currPos;
        if (value < currPos->value)
        {
            currPos = currPos->leftelement;
            if (currPos == NULL)
            {
                parent->leftelement = tempelement;
                parent->rightelement = NULL;
                return;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            currPos = currPos->rightelement;
            if (currPos == NULL)
            {
                parent->rightelement = tempelement;
                parent->leftelement = NULL;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("Binary Search Tree\n");
    insert(50);
    insert(30);
    insert(20);
    insert(40);
    insert(70);
    insert(60);
    insert(80);
    search(30);
    return 0;
}
```

[Here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qo8e.png)

Its a simple program for a binary search tree that has two functions insert and search
The problem is the insert function in vs code it goes in an infinite loop, I wrote printf("%d -> ", currPos->value); to know the current value but it prints random numbers

In the online compiler works fine as shown in the picture

[Here is the output of the online compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5c6G.png)

Comment: New element's `leftelement` and `rightelement` members should probably be set explicitly to NULL - `malloc()` does not zero out the memory, AFAIK.

Comment: Where is `main`?  Where are the include statements at the top?  Please attempt to simplify the code and post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that your code works in one environment and not another (likely) means that your issue lies in undefined behavior.

The problem is here that, unlike `calloc`, `malloc` **does not initialize the memory it allocates to zero**. Thus, the left and right elements may not in fact be NULL (instead they'll contain garbage values), and your tree will essentially be infinite. This is technically defined *behavior* of malloc, but the value of the memory it allocates is undefined, and thus doing any operation on it will result in undefined behavior.

If I were to guess the reason this is actually working is because the online compiler has already initialized its "virtual heap" to zero. In practice, it's pretty much always going to be garbage values (and even if it happens to be zero initialized already, it'd be impossible to count on that being the case.)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/malloc?view=msvc-170
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/calloc?view=msvc-170

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it

i changed malloc to calloc and it worked 
struct element *tempelement = (struct element *)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
-->
struct element *tempelement = (struct element *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct element));

Comment: Also another solution that worked is when i made the left and right elements explicitly to null

struct element *tempelement = (struct element *)malloc( sizeof(struct element));
    tempelement->value = value;
    tempelement->leftelement = NULL;
    tempelement->rightelement = NULL;